# C# Picture Box Zooming (Preserve Hard Edges)

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to figure out how to use the picturebox zoom, but I want to be able to keep the hard edges, When I zoom, the picture is blurry and not pixelated. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to custom-draw it using the lowest-possible quality for resizing. To custom-draw a control, you would handle its `Paint` event some way or another (ideally, you would subclass but I will make it more simple) so in the `Paint` handler for your PictureBox, place this code:

```
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
PictureBox picbox = (PictureBox)sender;
g.Clear(picbox.BackColor);

g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
// Draw the image using g.DrawImage()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found this http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=97904, which works amazingly :)

Answer (score 1):

Which is the exact component you are using? This is typically solved by switching the ImageStretch or ImageFit to NearestNeighbour. It's an filtering/interpolation setting that you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

PictireBox supports only basic zooming algorithms. As long as you have your image stored in memory you can implement your own zooming algorithms and feed the zoomed image to PictireBox and disabling any zooming features of the latter. 
You can use [this library](http://filters.sourceforge.net/) that implement advanced zooming algorithms.